# Get the last non zero column name of each row in R and create a separate column

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
ID  Jan Feb March April May Jun
ABC 0   1    0      0   2   1
DEF 1   2    1      0   0   0
GHI 0   10   0      1   0   0
JKI 0   0    2      0   0   0
MNO 3   0    0      0   0   0
```

I would like to get something like this

```
ID  Jan Feb March   April   May Jun LastMonth
ABC 0   1    0      0       1   1   Jun
DEF 1   1    1      0       0   0   March
GHI 0   1    0      1       0   0   April
JKI 0   0    1      0       0   0   March
MNO 1   0    0      0       0   0   Jan
```

I had written the following piece of code to get the index of last nonzero element of each row but this itself is having too many issues.

```
  df$last <- apply(df, 1, function(x) tail(x[x > 0.00001],1))
```

I get the new column as

```
character(0)
character(0)
character(0)
2
character(0)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this column instead of the actual number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to get the column index of the max value of the logical matrix (`df1[-1] != 0`) for each row and use that to get the column names

```
df1$LastMonth <- names(df1)[-1][max.col(df1[-1] != 0, 'last')]
df1$LastMonth
#[1] "Jun"   "March" "April" "March" "Jan"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKI", "MNO"), Jan = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 3L), Feb = c(1L, 2L, 10L, 0L, 0L), March = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 0L), April = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), May = c(2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Jun = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("ID", "Jan", 
"Feb", "March", "April", "May", "Jun"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Sorry! I should have created better data. I want the last nonzero column. Not max. I changed the question slightly.

Comment: @Morphenus  In that case change it to `max.col(df1[-1] != 0, 'last')`

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following in one line:

```
# get name of most recent month
df$Last_Month <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) last(colnames(df[-1])[x==1]))
```